# copy pscp a file from window server to to remote linux server

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file, pscp

I want to copy a directory (pscp) from windows server to Linux server 
The target place name on Linux server has to be new each time.When i run the below command,

```
> pscp -p -l root
> -pw mypassword -r C:\ProgramFiles\Mybackups\root@linux_server:/root/mywindowsbackups/$(date)
```

The command substitution $(date) doesn't work.
can any one suggest how would i run this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
:: This is stripping the `/` and `Day of the Week` from the date
set target_date=%date:/=-%
set target_date=%target_date:* =%

:: Copying the directory to the linux server based on this system's date
pscp -p -l root
-pw mypassword -r C:\ProgramFiles\Mybackups\root@linux_server:/root/mywindowsbackups/%target_date%
```

Comment: hey the above code works , it is creating directory on linux with current date but it is not copying the files from source(windows).I m getting following error
> pscp: unable to open /home/sudeep.m/05-18-2014: failure
Even this error comes if i specify some random name.

But when i run the command once again it is copying the files.

Comment: hey what if i m automating this task. its like i putting this command under.bat file
and this .bat file runs from windows task scheduler once in a week :)

Comment: If your question doesn't show the full task, then edit it and put in all the details.